# Javascript/jQuery library to replace variables in text

Tags: jquery, parsing, jquery-plugins, javascript

I have Javascript APIs where users call them with URLs.  I may need to replace some parts of the URL, for example they might call my ajax photo upload API with their upload URL:

```
http://www.example.com/photos/upload/${username};jsessionid=l2k34523
```

I then need to post to that URL when my code uploads a photo, replacing the ${username}.  I can tell them how to format that username variable in the URL, but I have to allow them to insert variables like this.

Is there a good Javascript or jQuery library to easily replace variables like the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `format` function can do the trick for you...

```
// add String prototype format function if it doesn't exist yet
if (jQuery.isFunction(String.prototype.format) === false)
{
    String.prototype.format = function () {
        var s = this;
        var i = arguments.length;
        while (i--)
        {
            s = s.replace(new RegExp('\\{' + i + '\\}', 'gim'), arguments[i]);
        }
        return s;
    };
}
```

So you can easily just use it as:

```
".../photos/upload/{0};jsessionid=l2k34523".format("JohnDoe");
```

or with multiple variables:

```
".../photos/upload/{0};jsessionid={1}".format("JohnDoe", "l2k34523");
```

Comment: Awesome function, although it doesn't work with named variables as the OP seemed to want. Just a note that it's not generally not the jQuery way to extended the prototypes of native objects. Typically you would attach a function to the jQuery object. Not important for functionality, but good to keep all code in the same style IMO.

Comment: @Michael: I agree with you on both but **firstly** named entities have probably been used for human readability as I understand it. If automation is introduced there's no need for named entities. Numbered ones can easily be used. And **secondly** I agree about extending native objects is bad practice but if you control this and keep it low there's no reason why not do things this way. But otherwise yes, **I'd suggest avoiding such things as well**. Generally.

Comment: @Michael: for named entities (exactly as he uses them) they can easily use the [jQuery tmpl plugin](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) that will do just that - convert a template string with named entities and put actual values in. But it seems a bit cumbersome if they don't use it anywhere else for anything more powerful. Simple functions like this one will make their code simpler and faster.

Comment: Agreed that you can come up with simpler than jQuery templates. But it's also easy to write a function which accepts named variables without much overhead. This of course allows variables to be moved around in the template without requiring all the replacements to be updated.

Comment: @Michael: you can move individual variable tokens around the string as you wish (or even use multitude of them in one string) without changing function parameter order. So `"{2}{0}{1}{0}".format("My", "World", "Sick");` will still work as expected according to token numbers. First parameter value `"My"` will be used twice on the second and fourth place.